# Overlapping shp maps in sf

Tags: r, ggplot2, shapefile, r-sf

I have two shapefiles that I read into R with `sf`.

- The first shp file covers **regions**.
- The second shp file covers **administrative districts**.
- The electoral districts are nested into regions.

I would like to overlay the two maps, then coloring each electoral district in a shade of the same color, having one color for each region.

I can plot the two and play around with colors but cannot overlay and coloring.

Files can be accessed here from the Italian National Institute of Statistics :
Reg1991_WGS84.shp:
http://www.istat.it/storage/cartografia/confini_amministrativi/non_generalizzati/Limiti1991.zip
CAMERA_PLURI_2017.shp: https://www.istat.it/storage/COLLEGI_ELETTORALI_2017.zip

```
library(sf)

italia_regions_1991<- read_sf("Limiti1991/Reg1991/Reg1991_WGS84.shp")  %>% select(geometry)
italia_camera_pluri <- read_sf("COLLEGI_ELETTORALI_2017/CAMERA_PLURI_2017.shp") %>% select(geometry)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider intersecting the regions & districts via `sf::st_intersection` - note however that there seems to be some overlap, as the regions and districts do not align perfectly (they mostly do, but not quite...)

I have also transformed the CRS to WGS84; perhaps not necessary, but works better with leaflet and the like...

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

italia_regions_1991<- read_sf("Reg1991_WGS84.shp") %>% 
  select(region = DEN_REG) %>% # this, and geometry by default
  st_transform(4326)

italia_camera_pluri <- read_sf("CAMERA_PLURI_2017.shp") %>% 
  select(geometry) %>% # only geometry...
  st_transform(4326) 

result <- italia_camera_pluri %>% 
  st_intersection(italia_regions_1991) 

ggplot(data = result, aes(fill = region)) +
  geom_sf()
```

[image]

Comment: This gets really close to what I was expecting to get to. However, i get the following error message `Error: 'st_normalize' is not an exported object from 'namespace:sf'`. I am trying to figure out whether this is due to package conflict.

Comment: I manage to plot using `plot(result)` but that leaves me with less control on the plotting

Comment: @MCS it seems your sf package is out of date - try updating it. `st_normalize` is a part of sf since v0.7-3 = February 2019 or so...

Answer (score 4):

This will get you started....

I used the `leafgl` library, since you are plotting alot of polylines/plygons... This performs (pretty)fast...

```
library(sf)
library(devtools)
library(leaflet)
#install leaflet with gl-suport
devtools::install_github("r-spatial/leafgl")
library(leafgl)
library(colourvalues)


#read shapefile regions and cast to polygons
sf1 <- st_read( "e:/two_shapes/Limiti1991/Reg1991/Reg1991_WGS84.shp" ) %>% st_cast( "POLYGON", warn = FALSE )
#read shapefile and cast to POLYGON and then to LINESTRING
sf2 <- st_read( "e:/two_shapes/COLLEGI_ELETTORALI_2017/COLLEGI_ELETTORALI_2017.shp") %>%
  st_cast( "POLYGON", warn = FALSE ) %>%
  st_cast( "LINESTRING", warn = FALSE )

#creaae color matrix for the regions( depending om DEN_REG), and for the polylines (=black)
col_region <- colour_values_rgb(sf1$DEN_REG, include_alpha = FALSE) / 255
col_lines  <- matrix(data = c(0,0,0), nrow = 1 )

#plot leaflet (takes some time)
leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>%
  addGlPolygons(data = sf1, color = col_region) %>%
  addGlPolylines( data = sf2, color = col_lines)
```

**result**

[image]